# Why doesn't find let me match multiple patterns?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, zsh

I'm writing some bash/zsh scripts that process some files. I want to execute a command for each file of a certain type, and some of these commands overlap. When I try to `find -name 'pattern1' -or -name 'pattern2'`, only the last pattern is used (files matching `pattern1` aren't returned; only files matching `pattern2`). What I want is for files matching either `pattern1` or `pattern2` to be matched.

For example, when I try the following this is what I get (notice only `./foo.xml` is found and printed):

```
$ ls -a
.        ..       bar.html foo.xml
$ tree .
.
├── bar.html
└── foo.xml

0 directories, 2 files
$ find . -name '*.html' -or -name '*.xml' -exec echo {} \;
./foo.xml
$ type find
find is an alias for noglob find
find is /usr/bin/find
```

Using `-o` instead of `-or` gives the same results. If I switch the order of the `-name` parameters, then only `bar.html` is returned and not `foo.xml`.

[image: Animated version]

**Why aren't `bar.html` and `foo.xml` found and returned? How can I match multiple patterns?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use parentheses in your `find` command to group your conditions, otherwise only 2nd `-name` option is effective for `-exec` command.

```
find . \( -name '*.html' -or -name '*.xml' \) -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't realize you could group them into different execution groups (i.e. `find . -name 'pattern1' -exec cmd1 \; -o -name 'pattern2' -exec cmd2 \;` (and omitting the `-o` causes only the first "group" to be used and executed)).

Comment: Yes indeed having 2 different `-exec` is also possible.

Answer (score 3):

### find utility

#### `-print` == default

If you just want to print file path and names, you have to drop `exec echo`, because *`-print`* is default.:

```
find . -name '*.html' -or -name '*.xml'
```

#### Order dependency

Otherwise, *`find` is read from left to right*, argument order is important!

So if you want to specify something, respect `and` and `or` precedence:

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec echo ">"{} \;  -o -name '*.xml' -exec echo "+"{} \;
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 4 \( -name '*.html' -o -name '*.xml' \) -exec echo {} \;
```

#### Expression `-print0` and `xargs` command.

But, for most cases, you could consider `-print0` with `xargs` command, like:

```
find . \( -name '*.html' -o -name '*.xml' \) -print0 |
    xargs -0 printf -- "-- %s -\n"
```

The advantage of doing this is:

- Only one (or few) *fork* for thousand of entry found. (Using `-exec echo {} \;` implies that one subprocess is run for **each** entry found, while `xargs` will build a long line with as many argument one command line could hold...)
- In order to work with filenames containing special character or whitespace, `-print0` and `xargs -0` will use the *`NULL`* character as the filename delimiter.

#### find ... -exec ... {} ... +

From some years ago, `find` command accept a new syntax for `-exec` switch.

Instead of `\;`, `-exec` switch could end with a plus sign `+`.

```
find . \( -name '*.html' -o -name '*.xml' \) -exec printf -- "-- %s -\n" {} +
```

With this syntax, `find` will work like `xargs` command, building long command lines for reducing forks.

Comment: Instead of using `-print0` and `xargs`, you can also reduce the number of forks by using `-exec COMMAND {} +` instead of `-exec COMMAND {} ;`, that is terminate `-exec` with `+` instead of `\;`. So `find .\ -name '*.html' -o -name '*.xml' \) -exec printf "\-- %s -\n" {} +` should do the same with less typing. (Also note the `\` before `--` which is needed - at least on my system - to prevent `printf` from interpreting the whole quoted pattern as command line parameter).

Comment: Hmm interesting new option, thanks @Adaephon. But I suspect thas this option may not exist in some different find implementation...

Comment: @Adaephon: Good point re `-exec ...+`; re interpretation of `--` (or `-`) in an _operand_ (non-option): the portable way to handle this is to use special option `--` _before_ the operand to signal unambiguously that whatever follows is an operand, not an option: `printf -- "-- %s -n \n" {}`

Comment: `-exec ... +` is POSIX-compliant; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html and thus preferable to the nonstandard `-print0` action; additionally `-exec ... +` requires less typing, it's also more efficient than the `-print0` / `xargs` combination.